# Window.open() behavior with Http://& Https:// on ios

Tags: jquery, html, ios

I have a form which has many fields including two icons which redirect user on a new tab.

1st Link

```
<span class="uk-input-group-addon">
  <a onclick="window.open('https://www.myURL.com/folder1/page_name', '_blank')" style="margin-bottom: -20px;"><i class="material-icons light-green-text text-darken-1">&#xE8B6;</i></a>
</span>
```

2nd Icon:

```
<span>
  <a onclick="window.open('http://secondURL.com/subPath/subPath/Pages/default.aspx', '_blank')" style="margin-bottom: -20px;"><i class="material-icons light-green-text text-darken-1"style="overflow:hidden">&#xE880;</i></a>
</span>
```

The first link works just fine and open page in a new window in any device & any platform.

the second link works fine and open page in a new window on windows platform only and some apple devices.

The difference between both links is the first link is `https` & the second link is `Http` only.

1. Is it the real problem ?
2. How many cases are there in which `window.open` will not open link in the new page ?
3. Is it possible that it opens up a new tab but the link won't show on the new tab like a blank new tab ?

Comment: Is this solution solve your problem : `<a href="https://www.myURL.com/folder1/page_name" target="_blank" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">` and `<a href="http://secondURL.com/subPath/subPath/Pages/default.aspx" target="_blank" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">`

Comment: i can try it. But, I would also like to understand `window.open()` 's behavior and all cases in which they won't work. please explain

Answer (score 0):

I would comment as it is not a proper answer, but I don't have enough rep; you should probably suspect the compatibility between iOS/the browser used and ASP.NET.